# Returning a variable - undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm reading Chrome's extension localStorage in my content script. If I log the variable to  console, everything works well. If I want to alert it, it says variable is undefined.

```
var data666;

chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "getLocalStorage", key: "autoplay"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response.data); // works perfectly
  data666 = response.data;
});

alert(data666); // does not work
```

**EDIT:** I need to use the variable (data666 in this case) outside the asynchronous function.

Comment: Just put whatever you need inside a function then call that function from within the callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

note that `sendRequest` is an asynchronous function, data's value will not be set until `sendRequest` executes the callback function.

Therefore, you need to move the alert statement into the callback function.

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "getLocalStorage", key: "autoplay"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response.data); // works perfectly
  data666 = response.data;
  alert(data666);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I already trid that, but I need to use the variable outside the function.

Comment: No, I'm afraid that you have to wrap the following procedures inside the callback function.

Comment: if you don't want it to be ugly, then take a look at https://github.com/caolan/async . I belive it will come handy.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, Qiao, but this looks like an overkill. Do you happen to know, if it is allowed to use an asynchronous function inside another?

Comment: It's common to see nested asynchronous functions, so get used to it :)